# Nodejs data exchange

Tags: node.js

I am working on an nodejs project at the moment and I have a row of data which needs to pass to the backend in order to update the information via ajax

I will try to describe the situation below.
In the HTML part i have something like this

```
<p id="tester">1+4+99</p>
```

And I must pass these to the `route`
, and therefore i can put 1+4+99 into the Api

```
var tester = req.query.tester;

url = url + "&tester=" + tester; //output should be &tester=1+4+99
```

It above is unclear, then just advice me how should I pass html element into nodejs file, please.

Comment: Needs more specifications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more detail, here is a simple jQuery implementation:

HTML

```
Click: <p id="input">1+4+99</p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").on("click", function(index){  
    val = $(this).text();
    $.get({
      url: 'http://example.com/path/to/api?tester=' + window.encodeURIComponent(val),

      success: function(data) {
        console.log(arguments);
      },
      error: function(erro) {
        console.error(arguments);
      }
    });
  });
});
```